Possible ambiguities of quantization
Quantization means to replace $p$ (the momentum) in the expressions of classical physical quantities with $-i\hbar\nabla$, so we get an operator belonging to each physical quantity. However, an expression (which defines a physical quantity) can be written in different forms, due to some identities, e.g.
$$(x+y)\cdot p=x\cdot p+y\cdot p\tag 1$$
(where $x$ is a vector). In this example, there isn't any problem, because $(x+y)\cdot\nabla=x\cdot\nabla + y\cdot\nabla$, so it doesn't matter if we quantize the right side or the left side of (1). However, there are vector identities which cease to be identities when we quantize them, e.g.
$$a\cdot (p\times a)=p(a\cdot a)-a(a\cdot p).\tag 2$$
This is the so-called "bac-cab identity" in the case of $c=a$, $b=p$, but the quantized version of it is
$$a\cdot (\nabla\times a)=\frac{1}{2}\nabla(a\cdot a)-(a\cdot \nabla)a\tag 3$$
(see here) so we will get different equations when we quantize the LHS or the RHS of (2).
This issue is unlikely to arise in the practice of conventional quantum mechanics, but I wonder how we could theoretically rule out such contradictions. Especially, since in a tricky way, using such kind of ambiguity of quantization, W. F. Eberlein showed that transforming a bit the expression of the Hamiltonian of the electron in magnetic field, then performing the quantization starting from an alternative form of the classical expression of the energy, the resulting Schrödinger equation excludes the presence of the magnetic field, and it can be corrected so that we replace the complex wave function to a pair of such functions, and if we do that, then instead of the Schrödinger equation, we will get the Pauli-equation.

Isn't $x\cdot p=p\cdot x$ an example already? And I don't see why we should bother about these difficulties, since QM is the underlying theory so we only need to make sure classical physics follows from QM, not the other way around. So "dequantization" is our problem, with einselection the only viable solution until now (probably...)

@JosBergervoet Not really. As I mentioned, Eberlein showed that by choosing another form of the classical expression of energy, we get Pauli instead of Schrödinger. Perhaps by using a third form, we get a yet better equation.

Are you aware of the Goenewold-van Hove theorem?

I wasn't aware of Eberlein contribution but yes the problem is well known and is due to the non-commutativity of the quantum operators. There are indeed several, different quantum mechanical Hamiltonian corresponding to the same classical one. Indeed $pq$ is probably the simplest example. Some quantum versions of this classical Hamiltonian have been linked to the Riemann hypothesis, their spectrum is approximately that of the zeroes on the critical line. Other version don't have this property so they are completely different operators.

see this post or this post.  The basic answer is: there is no unique answer.

Quantization is a mystery and not an unambiguous procedure. The classical-to-quantum map is one-to-many, as it contains $\hbar$-dependent information: what the 20th century was all about discovering. You have to guess which path to take, and check the experimental consequences. Normally, people choose the hermitian operator alternative.

What you are writing as a possible ambiguity of quantisation is actually very well-known inside the literature as the operator ordering problem, and all the pioneers spent quite a lot of typewriter time on the topic. It is actually very likely to appear in normal physics if you stray away from the standard route, and the resulting mess could easily just give you wrong physical predictions, which is why the pioneers felt that it was important enough to write about.
